# Why does the DNS server resolv DNS queries only for itself?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I have a problem with my own DNS server, which runs dnsmasq.

Here it is `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` (only un-commented lines):

```
# If you don't want dnsmasq to read /etc/resolv.conf or any other
# file, getting its servers from this file instead (see below), then
# uncomment this.
no-resolv

# Add other name servers here, with domain specs if they are for
# non-public domains.
#server=/localnet/192.168.0.1
server=151.100.4.2
server=151.100.4.13
```

When I try to resolve queries from the server, everything works great:

```
$ nslookup google.com
Server:  127.0.0.1
Address:  127.0.0.1#53

Non-authorative answer:
Name:    google.com
Address: 142.250.184.78
Name:    google.com
Address:  2a00:1450:4002:405::200e
```

However, when I try `ping google.com` from another host in the network, the DNS does not reply to the queries, even if it receives them. Here is the output of `tcpdump` on the DNS server:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n host 100.100.2.100
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:35:43.517755 IP 100.100.2.100.54996 > 100.100.1.2.53: 12795+ A? google.com. (28)
11:35:43.517844 IP 100.100.2.100.54996 > 100.100.1.2.53: 51213+ AAAA? google.com. (28)
11:35:48.522750 IP 100.100.2.100.54996 > 100.100.1.2.53: 12795+ A? google.com. (28)
11:35:48.522818 IP 100.100.2.100.54996 > 100.100.1.2.53: 51213+ AAAA? google.com. (28)
^C
4 packets captured
4 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

The other host is able to reach the network: sure enough, it pings 8.8.8.8 or any other IP. The problem is only with the name resolution.

I've surfed the internet looking for someone having the same problem, but I did not find anything. I really don't know what to try to solve the issue, since the DNS seems to work and it receives the queries, it just doesn't reply to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `dnsmasq` is probably answering queries only on address  127.0.0.1 (same computer only).

Read about: -i, --interface=

Check with `netstat -4panu` as root to find to which ports/iinterfaces is dnsmasq listening on.